# Access to i and i+1 element inside a ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm pretty new to Angular, so I can't solve this easy problem.
I would like to obtain the following html structure in AngularJS:

```
<div>
  <div>
    {{bar[i]}}
    {{bar[i+1]}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{bar[i+2]}}
    {{bar[i+3]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm iterating my model using `ng-repeat` in the following way:

```
<div ng-repeat="bar in bars">
  <div>
    <div ng-include="bar.html"></div>
    <div ng-include="bar.html"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the variable `bar` is, obviously, the same in both `ng-include`.

How to access instead to `i` and `i+1` element inside a `ng-repeat` loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$index` to access the current index:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-repeat="bar in ['a','b','c']">
    <div>
      <h1>Element: {{bar}}</h1>
      <div>{{$index*2}}</div>
      <div>{{$index*2+1}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then you can use `ng-include` as follows:

```
<div ng-include="bars[$index*2].html"></div>
<div ng-include="bars[$index*2+1].html"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I cannot access to ng-include html, it throws me 404. Is there another way to pass a variable to ng-include?

Comment: Did you try to use it like this: `<div ng-include ng-src="bars[$index*2].html"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the $index property

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

bars[$index + 1]